# From type in typescrit to string in js

Tags: javascript, typescript

Всем привет!

Подскажите, есть ли возможность из type в typescript перевести обратно в строку javascript?

Вот пример нерабочего кода который я хотел бы завести по нормальному, без as:

```
import { capitalizeFirstLetter } from "./capitalizeFirstLetter";

export const generateActionStatus = <N extends string, A extends string>({name, action}: {name: N, action: A}) => {
  type PendingType = `[Pending] ${Capitalize<typeof action>} ${Capitalize<typeof name>}`;
  type SuccessType = `[Success] ${Capitalize<typeof action>} ${Capitalize<typeof name>}`;
  type ErrorType = `[Error] ${Capitalize<typeof action>} ${Capitalize<typeof name>}`;

  const pending = `[Pending] ${capitalizeFirstLetter(action)} ${capitalizeFirstLetter(name)}` as PendingType;
  const success = `[Success] ${capitalizeFirstLetter(action)} ${capitalizeFirstLetter(name)}` as SuccessType;
  const error = `[Error] ${capitalizeFirstLetter(action)} ${capitalizeFirstLetter(name)}` as ErrorType;

  return {
    pending,
    success,
    error,
  };
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
export const capitalizeFirstLetter = <T extends string>(string: T) => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase()
```

Comment: **по нормальному, без as** - это как?

Comment: Поправил код в оснавном вопросе

имелось ввиду без такой конструкции

const pending = `[Pending] ${capitalizeFirstLetter(action)} ${capitalizeFirstLetter(name)}` as PendingType;

Comment: а зачем тебе вообще эти типы, если они только внутри? В любом случае, вместо `as PendingType` просто в определении переменной указывать тип `const pending: PendingType`

Comment: Я хочу что бы функция возвращала не обьект ключ строка, а именно объект ключ - определённый тип

Comment: чем не устраивает `const pending: PendingType`?

Comment: Происходит конфликт типов, приложил скриншот к основному вопросу

Вижу два выхода:
- каким то образом тип перевести в строку, но наверное это не возможно
- либо как то правильно собрать функцию capitalizeFirstLetter

Есть идеи как это решить правильно?

Comment: добавь определение функции `capitalizeFirstLetter`

Comment: Приложил второй скриншот, данной функции, как правильно написать это определение? Не понимаю

Comment: Добавь текстом ее

Comment: Это равноценно моей записи и ничего не меняет

Comment: меняет, с картинки нельзя скопировать текст

Comment: export const capitalizeFirstLetter = <T extends string>(string: T) => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase()

Вот функция, поэксперементируйте

Comment: и в сам вопрос тоже добавь

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `capitalizeFirstLetter` возвращает тип `string`, в то время как в типах ожидается `Capitalize`.

Для решения, достаточно указать правильный возвращаемый тип у `capitalizeFirstLetter`

```
const capitalizeFirstLetter = <T extends string>(string: T) => (string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)) as Capitalize<T>
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что `Capitalize` меняет только первый символ.

Comment: вы тут опять же используете `as`, это не то решение которе меня интересуе

вы добавили тот же костыль как и в `generateActionStatus`

Comment: @user447630, не совсем, там ты должен использовать `as` для каждой переменной. Здесь же ты используешь его в одной функции, для определения корректного типа возвращаемого значения.

Comment: У меня задача обойтись без `as` вовсе

Comment: + каждую переменную в основной функции все равно придется приводить к строковому литералу

вот так - `const pending = [Pending] ${capitalizeWord(action)} ${capitalizeWord(name)} as const;`

Безусловно Ваше решение немного упростило запись, но основную проблему не решила

Comment: @user447630, на текущий момент - это невозможно, так как операции со строками возвращают строки, а не литеральные типы ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Приводить к литералу не нужно, если у тебя есть готовые типы